# Would this mushroom make the basil dangerous to eat?

Tags: mycology, agriculture

My sister is growing basil in a planter on her balcony. Recently this big mushroom started growing there. Obviously we're not going to take a bite of the mushroom, but would its existence make the basil dangerous to eat?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: That could be a coprinus comatus / shaggy mane. If it is, the top will get pinkish then turn to black liquid . If that happens it was an edible mushroom.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I would say Leucocoprinus birnbaumii, which has a tendency to grow in pots.

Comment: @Ram Rachum From an academic perspective, I'm not aware of any cases where mushrooms caused toxicity in nearby plants. But consult a doctor for any medical advice.